# Basic PostGIS and PGRouting question

Tags: postgresql, pgrouting

I'm using OSX 10.6 and just downloaded and installed `PostgreSQL 9.0.2-1` and `pgRouting 1.0.5-1 for Postgres 9.0` from [here](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software%3apostgres).

I'm a confused what my next steps are though. I'd like to try loading a simple network into pgRouting and running a few different network routing analyses on it to test it out. However, I don't know where to begin.

How do I open PostgreSQL or pgRouting? I'm fairly comfortable with terminal commands and scripting, but as I installed precompiled versions, I don't know where anything is or what to get at. I have looked at the pgRouting [documentation](http://www.pgrouting.org/docs/tutorials.html), but I didn't see anything similar to my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was in the same boat as you just a couple of weeks ago and was able to get a shortest path with relative ease by using the tools/information below:

As previously mentioned, I use pgAdminIII as my GUI for writing SQL and managing tables.

As for getting started, I would definitely start by following along with @underdark's excellent [A Beginner’s Guide to pgRouting](http://underdark.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/a-beginners-guide-to-pgrouting/) blog posting from a few weeks ago. There are 3 posts in all, so be sure to look at newer posts than this one. I was able to get the shortest route implemented very quickly by following along.

I would also recommend the [PostGIS In Action](http://www.postgis.us/) eBook, which has a short section on using pgRouting.

If you want to download OpenStreetMap data, I found the [osm2po](http://osm2po.de/) utility to work fairly easy for loading and configuring the data, which then can give you a starting place and a configured road network in place.  Downloading a small spatial extent from [CloudMade](http://downloads.cloudmade.com/) will speed up your processing time and make it easier to learn, rather than downloading and working with say, an entire country.

Lastly, download a GIS software like [QGIS](http://www.qgis.org/) to visualize your network and routing outputs.

Comment: Here is another blog entry from Carson Farmer that you may find useful: http://www.carsonfarmer.com/?p=799

Answer (score 1):

We use pgAdmin (GUI of the command line)
http://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx

Install Guide and Good Tutorial from the Apple site:
Note: this is the official way of doing Postgres/PostGIS and pgrouting on Mac

[image]

Important > You need to create a new user

**Before installing PostgreSQL**, you’ll need to install a package called **readline**. The easiest way to get it is through the [Fink project](http://www.finkproject.org/). The Fink project’s goal is to port open-source Unix applications to Darwin and Mac OS X, and to make them available through an easy-to-use package manager. To install Fink, follow these directions. Make sure you’ve got the appropriate Fink installer for your version of OS X.

Once Fink is installed, open a terminal window and type the following to install readline:

http://developer.apple.com/internet/opensource/postgres.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions; I'll take a look at these links. After you install all these programs, how do you use them?

Comment: When PHPAdmin is installed - you can type http://localhost/phppgAdmin/index.php into your web browser - you should see the admin screen and logon to your postgres DB